# R Shiny reset input values for mychooser function of the Shiny gallery

Tags: r, shiny

I am still learning about Shiny and developing my own application.

The following widget allows to select columns however the user wants (with live example):

https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/custom-input-control.html

### *UI.R*

```r
source("chooser.R")

fluidPage(
  chooserInput("mychooser", "Available frobs", "Selected frobs",
    row.names(USArrests), c(), size = 10, multiple = TRUE
  ),
  verbatimTextOutput("selection")
)
```

### *server.R*

```r
function(input, output, session) {

  output$selection <- renderPrint(
    input$mychooser
  )

}
```

### *chooser.R*

```r
chooserInput <- function(inputId, leftLabel, rightLabel, leftChoices, rightChoices,
  size = 5, multiple = FALSE) {

  leftChoices <- lapply(leftChoices, tags$option)
  rightChoices <- lapply(rightChoices, tags$option)

  if (multiple)
    multiple <- "multiple"
  else
    multiple <- NULL

  tagList(
    singleton(tags$head(
      tags$script(src="chooser-binding.js"),
      tags$style(type="text/css",
        HTML(".chooser-container { display: inline-block; }")
      )
    )),
    div(id=inputId, class="chooser",
      div(class="chooser-container chooser-left-container",
        tags$select(class="left", size=size, multiple=multiple, leftChoices)
      ),
      div(class="chooser-container chooser-center-container",
        icon("arrow-circle-o-right", "right-arrow fa-3x"),
        tags$br(),
        icon("arrow-circle-o-left", "left-arrow fa-3x")
      ),
      div(class="chooser-container chooser-right-container",
        tags$select(class="right", size=size, multiple=multiple, rightChoices)
      )
    )
  )
}

registerInputHandler("shinyjsexamples.chooser", function(data, ...) {
  if (is.null(data))
    NULL
  else
    list(left=as.character(data$left), right=as.character(data$right))
}, force = TRUE)
```

### *www/chooser-binding.js*

```js
(function() {

function updateChooser(chooser) {
    chooser = $(chooser);
    var left = chooser.find("select.left");
    var right = chooser.find("select.right");
    var leftArrow = chooser.find(".left-arrow");
    var rightArrow = chooser.find(".right-arrow");

    var canMoveTo = (left.val() || []).length > 0;
    var canMoveFrom = (right.val() || []).length > 0;

    leftArrow.toggleClass("muted", !canMoveFrom);
    rightArrow.toggleClass("muted", !canMoveTo);
}

function move(chooser, source, dest) {
    chooser = $(chooser);
    var selected = chooser.find(source).children("option:selected");
    var dest = chooser.find(dest);
    dest.children("option:selected").each(function(i, e) {e.selected = false;});
    dest.append(selected);
    updateChooser(chooser);
    chooser.trigger("change");
}

$(document).on("change", ".chooser select", function() {
    updateChooser($(this).parents(".chooser"));
});

$(document).on("click", ".chooser .right-arrow", function() {
    move($(this).parents(".chooser"), ".left", ".right");
});

$(document).on("click", ".chooser .left-arrow", function() {
    move($(this).parents(".chooser"), ".right", ".left");
});

$(document).on("dblclick", ".chooser select.left", function() {
    move($(this).parents(".chooser"), ".left", ".right");
});

$(document).on("dblclick", ".chooser select.right", function() {
    move($(this).parents(".chooser"), ".right", ".left");
});

var binding = new Shiny.InputBinding();

binding.find = function(scope) {
  return $(scope).find(".chooser");
};

binding.initialize = function(el) {
  updateChooser(el);
};

binding.getValue = function(el) {
  return {
    left: $.makeArray($(el).find("select.left option").map(function(i, e) { return e.value; })),
    right: $.makeArray($(el).find("select.right option").map(function(i, e) { return e.value; }))
  }
};

binding.setValue = function(el, value) {
  // TODO: implement
};

binding.subscribe = function(el, callback) {
  $(el).on("change.chooserBinding", function(e) {
    callback();
  });
};

binding.unsubscribe = function(el) {
  $(el).off(".chooserBinding");
};

binding.getType = function() {
  return "shinyjsexamples.chooser";
};

Shiny.inputBindings.register(binding, "shinyjsexamples.chooser");

})();
```

Once the columns have been scrambled, we can't go back to the original order except reloading the application. I'd like to have an `actionButton` that resets all the columns of `mychooser` to their default values.

What I tried so far

### *UI.R*

```r
source("chooser.R")

fluidPage(
    chooserInput("mychooser", "Available frobs", "Selected frobs",
                 row.names(USArrests), c(), size = 10, multiple = TRUE
    ),
    actionButton(inputId = "resetcols", label = "Reset"),
    verbatimTextOutput("selection")
)
```

### *server.R*

```r
function(input, output, session) {

    colvalues <- row.names(USArrests)

    output$selection <- renderPrint(
        input$mychooser
    )

    eventReactive(input$resetcols, {
        output$mychooser <- row.names(USArrests)
    })

}
```

However, there's nothing happened and I don't know what can I do.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hmm... One would need to implement `binding.setValue`, that would allow to use `session$setInputValue`.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent would you care to explain a bit more please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the way.

Add this JS code in `chooser-binding.js`, e.g. after `binding.setValue`:

```
binding.receiveMessage = function (el, data) {
  $(".chooser select.left").empty();
  $(".chooser select.right").empty();
  if(data.left !== null){
    for(var i = 0; i < data.left.length; ++i){
      $(".chooser select.left")
        .append($("<option>" + data.left[i] + "</option>"));
    }
  }
  if(data.right !== null){
    for(var i = 0; i < data.right.length; ++i){
      $(".chooser select.right")
        .append($("<option>" + data.right[i] + "</option>"));
    }
  }
  var chooser = $(el);
  updateChooser(chooser);
  chooser.trigger("change");
};
```

Define the updater for `chooserInput`:

```
updateChooserInput <- function(session, inputId, left, right){
  session$sendInputMessage(inputId, list(right = right, left = left))
}
```

Now, here is an example:

```
# ui ####
ui <- fluidPage(
  br(),
  chooserInput("mychooser", "Available frobs", "Selected frobs",
               row.names(USArrests), c(), size = 10, multiple = TRUE
  ),
  verbatimTextOutput("selection"),
  br(),
  actionButton("update", "Update"),
  actionButton("reset", "Reset")
)

# server ####
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$selection <- renderPrint(
    input$mychooser
  )

  observeEvent(input$update, {
    updateChooserInput(session, "mychooser", 
                       left = c("aaa", "bbb", "ccc"), 
                       right = c("xxx", "yyy", "zzz"))
  })

  observeEvent(input$reset, {
    updateChooserInput(session, "mychooser", 
                       left = row.names(USArrests), 
                       right = c())
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will check it and come back to accept the answer